# what state will the active closer go when FIN-WAIT-2 time runs out?

Tags: sockets, tcp, protocols, network-protocols, time-wait

when FIN_WAIT2 time runs out and the last FIN doesn't come from the other side,what's the next state will the active closer be? `TIME-WAIT` or `CLOSED` ?

we know in linux system, FIN-WAIT-2 can be set in the file /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout: man tcp(7)

> - tcp_fin_timeout (integer; default: 60; since Linux 2.2)
>
>   > This specifies how many seconds to wait for a final FIN packet before the socket is ***forcibly closed***.  This is strictly a violation of the TCP specification, but required to prevent denial-of-service attacks.  In Linux 2.2, the default value was 180.
> - TCP_LINGER2 (since Linux 2.4)
>
>   > The lifetime of orphaned FIN_WAIT2 state sockets.This option can be used to override the system-wide setting in the file /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout for this socket.  This is not to be confused with the socket(7) level option SO_LINGER.  This option should not be used in code intended to be portable.

I'm not so sure about the state this TCP socket will go after `FIN_WAIT2` time runs out, be ***forcibly closed***,transit to `CLOSED`? or just jump into the `TIME-WAIT` state?

I made a test:

> 1 : echo 3 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout
>
> 2 : benchmark the tomcat runs on the linux

It turned out that lots of `TIME-WAIT` appeared in `netstat` and was accumulating, did that mean after the `FIN_WAIT2` time ran out, the socket jumped into `TIME-WAIT`?

One more question:
I changed this : 
`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse` as the others say: "to reuse the socket",and keep `tcp_fin_timeout:3`. but nothing changed,  `TIME-WAIT` was just accumulating. Does `tcp_tw_reuse` have nothing to do with the socket in `TIME-WAIT` state, the `TIME-WAIT` socket can't be reused ?

It seems like `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle` can reduce the `TIME-WAIT` count,and keep it a low level,leave the load balance problem alone.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [TCP/IP state diagram](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~agupta/cs340/project2/TCPIP_State_Transition_Diagram.pdf), `FIN_WAIT_2` transitions into `TIME_WAIT`.  So I would imagine that Linux simply transitions when `FIN_WAIT_2` times out when the `FIN` does not arrive.

Comment: I agree with you, and my test proved that too(if I made that test correctly), but the manual book in Linux says : This specifies how many seconds to wait for a final FIN packet before the socket is **forcibly closed**. Does it mean `FIN_WAIT2` will jump to `CLOSED`?